# react nonstateful component is somehow passed state

Tags: reactjs

Somehow, I am accidentally setting the state of an "ownee" component in React. I believe I am only passing in props, but when I look at the component in the React Dev Tools console, I see that the initial state of the owner was passed in correctly as props, but somehow, when I call "setState" in the owner, it then gets passed down to the ownee as state.

[image: Accidental State?]

Bizarrely, before I added the "activePlayer" state/prop, this same code worked fine. If it makes any difference, "activePlayer" is an object reference to one of the players in the "players" array.

Here's the owner's code in full:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return{
      players: [],
      neck: [],
      activePlayer: null
    }
},

componentDidMount(){
    self = this;

    socket.on("pass initial state", function(data){
      self.setState({players: data.players, 
                  neck: data.neck,
                  activePlayer: data.activePlayer})
      }) 

    socket.on('new player added', function(data){
      self.setState({players: data.players});
      })

    socket.on('game started', function(data){
      self.setState({neck: data.neck,
                activePlayer: data.activePlayer})
    })
  },

render: function () {
    return (
      <div id='App'>
        <OpponentsDIV players={this.state.players} activePlayer={this.state.activePlayer}/>
  </div>)}
    });

module.exports = App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main-container'));
```

And here's the "ownee" (OpponentsDIV)

```
var OpponentsDIV = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    self = this;

    var playerList = this.props.players.map(function(player){
        var key = "playerDIV"+ player.name;
      var active = false;
      if (self.props.activePlayer === player.name){
        active = true;
      };
        return <PlayerDIV player={player} key={key} active={active}/>
    });

    return (
      <div  className="layoutDIV" id='OpponentsDIV'>
        OpponentsDIV
        {playerList}
        <ChatDIV />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = OpponentsDIV;
```

Comment: When you call `setState` in App, it forces a call to `render()`, as a result, `OpponentsDIV` is also re-rendered, but with the new `state` data as props.

Comment: For the record, "ownee" and "owner", might be better represented as "child" and "parent"

Comment: @lux, that's what I thought was happening. But why does OpponentsDIV have state at all? You can see in the screenshot that its props were passed in correctly upon initial render (they're the same as GetInitialState on App). But then somehow I set the STATE of OpponentsDIV instead of its props, and now it has both STATE and PROPS, despite the fact that it should never have STATE.

Comment: @azium The React docs make a distinction between owner/ownee and parent/child relationships: the latter is just used for DOM objects, I think. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Is it possible that `state` from the screenshot is actually from `App`? You'll note from the screen that `neck` is included in that state object, but `neck` isn't even passed to `OpponentsDIV` as a prop. Very strange. Also, I just did a `console.log` on one of my own components that has no state, and `state: null` in my output...If you plop this example down in a Plunkr or Codepen, I'd happily take a further look. Does seem very strange at first glance.

Comment: @KSully2 ahh I suppose you are correct. Colloquially though people say parent and child because a React app is one big tree.

Comment: good to know, @azium, I'll only use owner/ownee in the future if I need to be technically specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: because I missed the "var" in the statement:

```
self = this;
```

within OpponentsDIV, I believe that the scopes of my "self" and/or "this" variables was overlapping, causing React to believe that "self" referred to OpponentsDIV instead of App.

The fix was to simply put "var" in front of the statement on line3 of OpponentsDIV. I can consistently reproduce both fixing and breaking the code by simply adding or removing "var." Ah, Javascript.

Comment: Do you need to target really old browsers? You can avoid the whole `self` nonsense with arrow functions.